# Conditional Formatting Not Working On My Machine, But Does On Other Machines!

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I hope someone can help me with my current issue. I have an issue that my Google Sheets are not working on my Windows computer, but do work when I use the Sheets with other computers!

I make educational resources on spreadsheets where a picture is produced as correct answers are type in. The pictures are shown through use of conditional formatting. I originally make these on Microsoft Excel and then import them to Google Sheets. I have included a link to one of them below - I would be interested to know if people have any problems/comments!

My issue is, all of the sheets that I have made are not working properly when I use Google Sheets on my computer. What happens is after the first answer cell is typed in a massive chunk of the picture is shown and the conditional formatting becomes unresponsive. I have the same issues using both Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge browsers!  Also, concerning the conditional formatting for blank cells option - when converting to Google Sheets it is put to the lowest priority order (when it needs to be the highest) and if I try to move the order then Google Sheets just reloads.

However, when I use my Google Sheets on a different computer in my house then the sheets work exactly as expected! (Today I tried the sheets on a Macintosh and another Windows machine.)

Can anyone please make any suggestions as to why my Google Sheets will not work properly on my machine, but work when I change computers? I note when I have the sheets open in two different computers so a live picture is seen then the sheet displays what it should on the other machine, but not my Windows computer!

Thank you!

[Example Of One Of My Google Sheets!](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-4KiAxM6cHo-f3W7IsQP52IOTdHAhTqoNT8XLkgym5w/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: EDIT - I think I have found an answer! I deleted the cache, cookies and disabled extensions. (I have a number of extensions which I use for web programming eg. JavaScript development.) From what I can see now Google Sheets works as intended. I hope people are not annoyed with me for posting a solution so soon, but it has been a very long journey to identify why my spreadsheets were not working in Google Sheets!

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Self-answering is encouraged. Please bear in mind that solutions should be posted as an answer, not as a comment, either as question edit. Ref. [Can I answer my own question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found an answer!

I deleted the cache, cookies and disabled extensions. (I have a number of extensions which I use for web programming eg. JavaScript development.) From what I can see now Google Sheets works as intended.

I hope people are not annoyed with me for posting a solution so soon, but it has been a very long journey to identify why my spreadsheets were not working in Google Sheets!